# android sdk - can't get it working on ubuntu 12

Tags: android, ubuntu, sdk

I'm trying to follow the instructions found in the URL below to install the android sdk on my ubuntu box.

http://forums.team-nocturnal.com/showthread.php/772

But... I can't seem to add the personal archive nilarimogard without getting an error message.
when i attempt:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
```

I get the message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 125, in 
>       ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 80,
>   in get_ppa_info_from_lp
>       curl.perform() pycurl.error: (7, "couldn't connect to host") root@jll:/home/me/Documents#

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to just edit /etc/apt/sources.list manually and add:

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu oneiric main